# Reverse Cumulative Sum - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have to perform a query that return the reverse cumulative sum with every stage that the client has passed, jumping the two firsts.
The database register every customer that have been discarded and the stage that it happen.

This is my sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE descartados
(`stage` varchar(15), `date` datetime);

INSERT INTO descartados
(`stage`, `date`)
VALUES
('Entrada', '2021-01-18 13:03:36'),
('Filtro 2', '2021-01-11 19:40:47'),
('Filtro 2', '2021-01-11 13:28:54'),
('Filtro 2', '2021-01-11 19:44:16'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-11 13:28:24'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-11 13:29:28'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-11 18:17:26'),
('Filtro 2', '2021-01-11 19:40:22'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-11 18:35:32'),
('Filtro 2', '2021-01-11 18:40:27'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-12 17:49:03'),
('Filtro 2', '2021-01-12 17:19:15'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-12 12:37:41'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-12 18:17:38'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-13 12:12:27'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-13 12:13:00'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-12 19:00:05'),
('Filtro 1', '2021-01-18 12:48:21'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-12 17:52:18'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-13 12:13:53'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-13 12:43:28'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-13 13:13:11'),
('Entrada', '2021-01-13 13:15:13'),
('Agendados', '2021-01-13 13:15:13'),
('Qualificados', '2021-01-13 13:15:13'),
('Agendados', '2021-01-13 13:15:13'),
('Qualificados', '2021-01-13 13:15:13'),
('Agendados', '2021-01-13 13:15:13');

SELECT descartados.stage, descartados.date FROM descartados;
```

| stage | date |
| --- | --- |
| Filtro 2 | 2020-09-15 17:12:25 |
| Entrada | 2020-09-15 14:34:56 |
| Entrada | 2020-09-16 16:55:17 |
| Filtro 1 | 2020-09-15 18:24:53 |
| Entrada | 2020-09-16 14:41:04 |
| Entrada | 2020-09-16 14:42:55 |

This is my actual query and the result.

```
SELECT IF(GROUPING(descartados.stage), "Total", descartados.stage) AS Estagio, 
COUNT(*) as Contagem, 
SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER by FIELD(Estagio, "Qualificados", "Agendados", "Filtro 2", "Filtro 1", 
"Entrada", "Total")) AS "Funil de Entrada"
FROM descartados
WHERE descartados.date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31'
GROUP BY descartados.stage WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY FIELD(Estagio, "Total", "Entrada", "Filtro 1", "Filtro 2", "Agendados", "Qualificados")
```

| Estagio | Contagem | Funil de Entrada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total | 28 | 56 |
| Entrada | 16 | 28 |
| Filtro 1 | 1 | 12 |
| Filtro 2 | 6 | 11 |
| Agendados | 3 | 5 |
| Qualificados | 2 | 2 |

I want to repeat the "Total" and "Entrada" rows, and start the reverse cumulative from "Entrada". I tried to introduce LAG, but I was not able to do it.

This is my desired output:

| Estagio | Contagem | Funil de Entrada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total | 28 | 28 |
| Entrada | 16 | 16 |
| Filtro 1 | 1 | 12 |
| Filtro 2 | 6 | 11 |
| Agendados | 3 | 5 |
| Qualificados | 2 | 2 |

How can I do that?

Comment: Try not to use jargon like purchase funnel when asking - those not in whatever discipline this comes from may be discouraged from answering.but if you must include representative sample data and expected outcome to clarify

Comment: Understood @P.Salmon. I have updated it, thank you.

Comment: *This is my sample data* I do not see where the data for sample output is taken from. Provide complete sample data and according desired sample output.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you, I wasn't understanding what was missing.

Comment: You seem so close.